# django views simple access controll with api key

Tags: django, web-services, api

I have a simple webservice app which needs some kind of control over the applications that are allowed to access it.

I don't need a oauth or something like that, all I want is to generate a key of some kind which needs to be send with a request. I could generate those keys by hand, there is no need for an automatism. But I have to be able to close the access for a specific key if it gets misused.

I have some ideas on how to do that, but wanted to ask you for some best practice tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could be inspired by  Tastypie's method of generating API keys. See the relevant
code [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/models.py#L35).

In your specific case, it seems that you're going to have many API keys which are valid
at the same time. So you should replace this:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='api_key')
```

with:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='api_keys')
```

and you should add a field similar to:

```
is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

that will denote if a certain key associated with a `user` is valid or not.